# Css bar with text underneath it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a bar chart. It is to view how many surveys are done, not started and not available. I want to show numbers under the bar like so:
[image: bar chart example]

I already have the bar:

```css
.bar {
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #484848;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #535353, #919191);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div1 {
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #65ea4e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5abe43, #64ed4e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div1:hover {
  content: 'Klaar';
}

.div2 {
  height: 2em;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, darkred, red);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div1:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.div2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltiptext {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  margin-top: 2em;
  background-color: #484848;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="div1">5<span class="tooltiptext">Aantal afgemaakte enquêtes</span></div>
  <div class="div2">2<span class="tooltiptext">Aantal niet afgemaakte enquêtes</span></div>
</div>
```

So what do I need to add or change to get my bar the same to the bar in the photo?

Comment: by any chance are you suppose to use js?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Im not sure for now, but at the end it should be flexible because the value has to come from a database

Comment: Also? Will there be only 3 sections and 4 values all the time or they might vary?

Comment: I also assume that the width of the sections should be a % of the total? JS is **definitely** going to be required here. The positioning of the numbers (with a minor HTML adjustment is simple) but the rest is probably too broad.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Mostly three but as I said flexible would be nice for in the future. There might be added one more color for the started but not done surveys

Comment: @Paulie_D You are correct. I also expected to be needing JS

Comment: So @SilkeNL as @Paulie_D said, to completely provide the solution, it will be too broad. Please try something with `js` and narrow down your problem. :)

Comment: I understand. Can you and @Paulie_D provide an answer to position the ciphers with only css? So I type in the values for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positioning the numbers requires a minor HTML structure change and then it's a matter of absolute positioning and a transform.

```css
.bar {
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #484848;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #535353, #919191);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.bar>div {
  position: relative;
}

.bar>div .value {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: -25px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.div1 {
  height: 2em;
  flex: 0 050%;
  background-color: #65ea4e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5abe43, #64ed4e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div2 {
  height: 2em;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, darkred, red);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="div1">
    <span class="value">5</span>
  </div>

  <div class="div2">
    <span class="value">2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've already done it for the tooltips, so you can simply repeat that. Add a `<span>` to the numbers and apply similar styling:

```css
.bar {
  height: 2em;
  display: flex;
  border: 3px solid darkgrey;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-color: #484848;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #535353, #919191);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div1 {
  height: 2em;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #65ea4e;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5abe43, #64ed4e);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div2 {
  height: 2em;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, darkred, red);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.div1:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.div2:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.text {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.tooltiptext {
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #484848;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
  <div class="div1"><span class="text">5</span><span class="tooltiptext">Aantal afgemaakte enquêtes</span></div>
  <div class="div2"><span class="text">2</span><span class="tooltiptext">Aantal niet afgemaakte enquêtes</span></div>
</div>
```